# Why don't work custom theme layout extension in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, layout-update

i have created custom theme

```
/app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName
```

It works fine. I see it in the admin, styles from it are applied, etc. But When I try to extend module layout Magento 2 don't see xml. I have created:

```
/app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

wich contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.compare.sidebar" destination="sidebar.additional" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

And there are no results at all. If I place this rule in

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

move works fine. But in custom theme xml just being ignored.
I try to break it like

```
    <body
```

and page don't fail with error. So I think xmls from theme are ignored completely.

And yes, I

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

before checking.

Answer (score 2):

Look like I have find a reason: in the data base in table type of theme was 1, and other have 0. 
When I change type to 0 and `php ./bin/magento cache:flush` XML start to work properly. 
Lite googling show that there are Physical, Virtual, Staging types.

But I don't get why my custom theme was set to Virtual type (1?), Is there any way to set type other then with SQL UPDATE, and what is differences in types.

Would be grateful for any documentation links. Can't find anything official yet…

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4330#issuecomment-243728148 — some information on theme initialisation flow

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to redeploy the static content? Only clearing caching won't work if you haven't switched the deploy mode.

Comment: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` ?

Yes, sure, no help. 
But I don't really think that it was needed anyway.

Comment: That isn't needed if you're running in developer mode

Comment: yep, developer mode it is.